# Converting Hex to Float SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point, hex

I am trying to find a way of converting `HEX` to a `float` in SQL Server.

An example value is `0x42c80000` which corresponds to `100.00`.

It is easy to convert this `Hex` value to an `Int` using `CONVERT` but I can not find the float conversion equivalent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DECLARE @BinaryFloat AS VARBINARY(4); 
SET @BinaryFloat = CONVERT(VARBINARY, '0x42c80000',1);

SELECT SIGN(CAST(@BinaryFloat AS INT))
  * (1.0 + (CAST(@BinaryFloat AS INT) &  0x007FFFFF) * POWER(CAST(2 AS REAL), -23))
  * POWER(CAST(2 AS REAL), (CAST(@BinaryFloat AS INT) & 0x7f800000) / 0x00800000 - 127)
```

Wish I could claim credit, but alas: http://multikoder.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/converting-varbinary-to-float-in-t-sql.html

Also, interesting blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2010/11/01/how-it-works-sql-parsing-of-numbers-numeric-and-float-conversions/

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77583753/77584123#77584123) that includes the equivalent IEEE *double precision* (8 byte) binary-to-float conversion, and encapsulates both conversions in user-defined functions.