# MySql function: Hexadecimal conversation to Float

Tags: mysql, sql, floating-point, type-conversion, hex

I have a bit of a challenge in converting a hexadecimal string into a float.

Here is an example:

Hex:
`3F62 0C3C`

Binary: `00111111011000100000110000111100`

Conversion result (float big endian):
`0.8829992`

Can this conversion be achieved with MySql functions and, if possible, how?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I assume you have your hexadecimal string in some sort of `TEXT` type:

```
SELECT @hexstring := '3F62 0C3C'
```

The first thing you need to do is to convert it to a decimal. You can do this using the `CONV` function. For that, first remove the whitespace from the string with the `REPLACE` function. Depending on the parameters of the `CONV` function, you can e.g. get a binary or a decimal representation:

```
SELECT @binvalue := CONV(REPLACE(@hexstring, ' ', ''), 16, 2)   -- 111111011000100000110000111100
SELECT @decvalue := CONV(REPLACE(@hexstring, ' ', ''), 16, 10)  -- 1063390268
```

From the decimal representation, you can calculate your float (based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37524172/14015737)):

```
SELECT SIGN(@decvalue) *  (1.0 + (@decvalue &  0x007FFFFF) * POWER(2.0, -23))
  * POWER(2.0, (@decvalue & 0x7f800000) / 0x00800000 - 127)
```

Result:

```
0.8829991817474365
```

Or all in one:

```
SELECT SIGN(CONV(REPLACE(@hexstring, ' ', ''), 16, 10)) 
  * (1.0 + (CONV(REPLACE(@hexstring, ' ', ''), 16, 10) &  0x007FFFFF) 
  * POWER(2.0, -23)) 
  * POWER(2.0, (CONV(REPLACE(@hexstring, ' ', ''), 16, 10) & 0x7f800000) / 0x00800000 - 127)
```

Test all of it together in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=873e433be03f691738b71bd7172ecec9).

Comment: @rhh you're very welcome. However, using comments to say thank you isn't necessary. Feel free to accept (like you already did) and [upvote answers you find useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) to express your thanks. Cheers!