# Convert float to varbinary and back to float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert a `float` to `varbinary`, but when I try to get it back, I can't get the correct value.

For example:

```
select 
    convert(varbinary(max), convert(float, '11000000000000')) -> "0x42A402462F600000"

select 
    convert(varchar(max), convert(varbinary(max), convert(float, '11000000000000'))) -> "B¤F/`"
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I get my float after it's been converted to binary?

The why of this question?
Just to know how sql works and how manage correctly conversions data.
Now, thanks @TN, i know how do it.

Comment: You have the character string '11000000000000', which you want as float, to convert to varbinary. Which varbinary result do you expect?

Comment: `convert a float to varbinary` why and what kind of output do you expect? The `why` is the most important question - why do you care about SQL Server's internal representation of floats?

Comment: Both results are correct anyway. You asked SQL Server to treat the bytes as if they were characters, not to format them as a HEX string. The result will look like garbage unless the bytes come from actual text. What are you trying to do? Format a float as a hex string? Once again, why?

Comment: If you are trying to get the hex string you need a parameter of `2` in the `CONVERT`- `select convert(varchar(max),convert(varbinary(max),convert(float,'11000000000000')),2)`

Comment: thank you Martin. and how i can get back my float?

Comment: What does this mean? Use the original float. Or format the float as a string. Or return the value to the client as a float, not a string. Why do you think you need to convert anything? This is almost certainly [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X and assume it can be solved by Y (getting a value's internal representation as a hex string). When that doesn't work, you ask about Y, not the real problem X

Comment: RE: getting back the float - looks like you can't easily. There is no supported data conversion from binary to float. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Why not use numeric instead. What are you doing with float / binary anyway

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed. "How can I get my float after it's been converted to binary?" seemed pretty clear to me. The obvious answer would have been `CONVERT(FLOAT, @Binary)` or `CAST(@Binary AS FLOAT)`, but SQL (for unknown reasons) does not support that particular conversion. Questions of "Why are you using binary" or "Why are you using float" seem off topic and should not be reasons for a close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated. See my recommended solution in Addendum 2 below.*

I find it strange that SQL Server will let you save the internal float representation off as binary and will not let you reverse that operation. (Makes no sense to me). It lets you do bidirectional conversions to/from binary with nearly every other type, including the various date/time types. The only other exceptions are text/ntext, but those are obsolete pointer-to-text-storage types.

I'm guessing that you are combining this with other data in a binary string and need to be able to map everything back to their exact original values.

The only alternatives I can offer are (1) Convert to VARCHAR using the lossless conversion format - `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), value, 3)`, convert from there to binary, and reverse the process to restore the original float value, or (2) Convert to the X coordinate of a Geometry::Point, from there to binary, and reverse that process (using the geometry .STX property) to restore the original float value. Both options produce binary representations several times longer than a direct conversion to binary.

It seems like you will need to choose the "**best bad option**."

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IFa51nNw) for a demo.

**ADDENDUM:**

I found a potentially better, *but undocumented* way of performing a float to binary to float roundtrip.

After examining the binary representation of `GEOMETRY::Point(value, 0, 0)`, I found that its binary representation was `0x00000000010C...0000000000000000` where the `...` is the reversed binary representation of the float. Using this knowledge, it is possible to take a binary representation of the original float, construct a binary representation of a GEOMETRY::Point, convert to GEOMETRY, and extract the original float value.

The following function encapsulated this technique.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ConvertBinaryToFloat(@FloatBinary VARBINARY(MAX)) RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@FloatBinary IS NULL OR LEN(@FloatBinary) <> 8) RETURN NULL

    DECLARE @PointBinary VARBINARY(MAX) =
        0x00000000010c
        + CAST(REVERSE(@FloatBinary) as VARBINARY(MAX))
        + 0x0000000000000000
    DECLARE @Point GEOMETRY = @PointBinary
    RETURN @Point.STX
END
```

```
-- Float -> binary -> float (using custom function)
DECLARE @F1 FLOAT = ACOS(-1)
DECLARE @B VARBINARY(MAX) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @F1)
DECLARE @F2 FLOAT = dbo.ConvertBinaryToFloat(@B)

SELECT @F1, @B, @F2
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @F1), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @F2) -- Confirm identical
```

This does precisely what `CONVERT(FLOAT, @Binary)` should do, if it were supported by SQL Server.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BlDMS2K5) that demonstrates the prior methods and this new method. Both a directly coded conversion and a function that encapsulates that conversion are shown.

Again, I stress that this is diving into undocumented representations, but I do not believe these representations would ever change because it would break all existing databases that store geometry.

**ADDENDUM2:**

I found yet another method that directly deconstructs the binary into components and uses them to build up the original float value.  This relies on the documented representation for IEEE 754 Double Precision values.

(This solution was adapted from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523874/), which used a similar calculation for single precision (SQL Server real) values.)

```
CREATE FUNCTION ConvertBinaryToFloat(@Binary VARBINARY(MAX)) RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    -- IEEE 754 Double Precision binary to float
    -- Layout:
    --   64 bits total
    --   1 bit sign
    --   11 bits exponent (excess 1023)
    --   52 bits fractional mantissa  (with implicit leading 1) = 1.xxxxx
    -- Does not support IEEE NaN, +Inf, or -Inf values. 

    IF (@Binary IS NULL OR DATALENGTH(@Binary) <> 8) RETURN NULL
    IF (@Binary = 0x0000000000000000) RETURN 0
    IF (@Binary = 0x8000000000000000) RETURN -0e0 -- IEEE Negative 0

    DECLARE @Int64 BIGINT = CAST(@Binary AS BIGINT)
    DECLARE @One FLOAT = 1
    DECLARE @Two FLOAT = 2
    DECLARE @Mantissa FLOAT = @One + (@Int64 & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFF) * POWER(@Two, -52)
    DECLARE @Exponent INT = (@Int64 & 0x7ff0000000000000) / 0x0010000000000000 - 1023

    IF (@Exponent = 1024) RETURN NULL -- Unsupported special: Inf, -Inf, NaN
  
    RETURN SIGN(@Int64) * @Mantissa * POWER(@Two, @Exponent)
END
```

The equivalent conversion from Binary to Real (IEEE Single Precision) is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ConvertBinaryToReal(@Binary VARBINARY(MAX)) RETURNS REAL
AS
BEGIN
    -- IEEE 754 Single Precision binary to float
    -- Layout:
    --   32 bits total
    --   1 bit sign
    --   8 bits exponent (excess 127)
    --   23 bits fractional mantissa  (with implicit leading 1) = 1.xxxxx
    -- Does not support IEEE NaN, +Inf, or -Inf values. 

    IF (@Binary IS NULL OR DATALENGTH(@Binary) <> 4) RETURN NULL
    IF (@Binary = 0x00000000) RETURN 0
    IF (@Binary = 0x80000000) RETURN -0e0 -- IEEE Negative 0

    DECLARE @Int32 INT = CAST(@Binary AS INT)
    DECLARE @One REAL = 1
    DECLARE @Two REAL = 2
    DECLARE @Mantissa REAL = @One + (@Int32 & 0x007FFFFF) * POWER(@Two, -23)
    DECLARE @Exponent INT = (@Int32 & 0x7f800000) / 0x00800000 - 127

    IF (@Exponent = 128) RETURN NULL -- Unsupported special: Inf, -Inf, NaN

    RETURN SIGN(@Int32) * @Mantissa * POWER(@Two, @Exponent)
END
```

Test results (double precision / SQL Server float):

| Value | Binary | Result | ResultBinary | Compare | CompareBinary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0x0000000000000000 | 0 | 0x0000000000000000 | Equal | Identical |
| 0.5 | 0x3FE0000000000000 | 0.5 | 0x3FE0000000000000 | Equal | Identical |
| 1 | 0x3FF0000000000000 | 1 | 0x3FF0000000000000 | Equal | Identical |
| 11000000000000 | 0x42A402462F600000 | 11000000000000 | 0x42A402462F600000 | Equal | Identical |
| 0.333333333333333 | 0x3FD5555555555555 | 0.333333333333333 | 0x3FD5555555555555 | Equal | Identical |
| 142857142857143 | 0x42E03DB0A81DB6DB | 142857142857143 | 0x42E03DB0A81DB6DB | Equal | Identical |
| 1.4142135623731 | 0x3FF6A09E667F3BCD | 1.4142135623731 | 0x3FF6A09E667F3BCD | Equal | Identical |
| 3.14159265358979 | 0x400921FB54442D18 | 3.14159265358979 | 0x400921FB54442D18 | Equal | Identical |
| 2.71828182845905 | 0x4005BF0A8B145769 | 2.71828182845905 | 0x4005BF0A8B145769 | Equal | Identical |
| 0 | 0x8000000000000000 | 0 | 0x8000000000000000 | Equal | Identical |

Test results (single precision / SQL Server real):

| Value | Binary | Result | ResultBinary | Compare | CompareBinary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0x00000000 | 0 | 0x00000000 | Equal | Identical |
| 0.5 | 0x3F000000 | 0.5 | 0x3F000000 | Equal | Identical |
| 1 | 0x3F800000 | 1 | 0x3F800000 | Equal | Identical |
| 1.1E+13 | 0x55201231 | 1.1E+13 | 0x55201231 | Equal | Identical |
| 0.3333333 | 0x3EAAAAAB | 0.3333333 | 0x3EAAAAAB | Equal | Identical |
| 1.428571E+14 | 0x5701ED85 | 1.428571E+14 | 0x5701ED85 | Equal | Identical |
| 1.414214 | 0x3FB504F3 | 1.414214 | 0x3FB504F3 | Equal | Identical |
| 3.141593 | 0x40490FDB | 3.141593 | 0x40490FDB | Equal | Identical |
| 2.718282 | 0x402DF854 | 2.718282 | 0x402DF854 | Equal | Identical |
| 0 | 0x80000000 | 0 | 0x80000000 | Equal | Identical |

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a6CNwslA) for a demo.

Comment: hi, you understad my goal.
and yes, i don't undestand why can't reverse the conversation.
thank you for answer, i never saw GEOMETRY::Point function. now i study it

Comment: Because you are under the impression that converting that `float` value back to a `varchar` gets you the same literal. It does **not**, it yields `'1.1e+013'`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NJsFCR_l) @elle0087 .

Comment: @Thom. yes i know, but is not allowed convert directly varbinary to float...crazy...

Comment: I suppose the question then is *why* do you want to convert a floating point value to a binary value, @elle0087 . As has been mentioned in the comments, this all had the smell of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) and likely what you should be asking about is that X, not the Y.

Comment: @ThomA - The float *value* representations for both 11000000000000 and 1.1e+013 are identical, despite the different presentations. Both are stored as hex values 0x42A402462F600000.

Comment: `'11000000000000'` and `'1.1e+013'` do *not* have the same binary value, @TN . They are (very) different `varchar` values. They represent the same floating point value, sure, but their binary values are entirely different.

Comment: @ThomA - The OP is interested in a round trip from float to binary and back to float, not varchar.

Comment: @elle0087 - Updated yet again is a new *best* and recommended solution, including both binary to float (IEEE double precision) and binary to real (IEEE single precision) options that both do what `CONVERT(float/real, @binary)` should have implemented.

Comment: @TN - thank you again...very clever and very clear. very impossible for me to reach alone!

Comment: @elle0087 - Happy to help. I am inclined to go back and remove the `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), value, 3)` and `GEOMETRY::Point(value, 0, 0)` portions of the answer (or move them to the end) if you think the direct conversion functions in ADDENDUM2 would serve your needs.

Comment: glad to leraned something new. you could keep the first answer as "no good way", just to know for everyone how don't do. thank you again!

Comment: @elle0087 - One more tweak/bug-fix. I changed the LEN() to DATALEN() in ConvertBinaryToFloat() function above. The LEN() function doesn't count trailing spaces (even in binary data) and was yielding the wrong length on values that happened to end with a hex 0x20. The demo link now has additional test data generators (currently commented out).